# How to update classes on binded variable update in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a binded span value on one of my object property

```
<span class="badge badge-primary">@MyObject?.MyProperty</span>
```

I want to be able to update my span classes in respect to it's content (the binded variable)

The only way I can think of is to bind the variable a second time inside an attribute of the span and declare my css classes accordingly

```
<span class="badge badge-primary" value="@MyObject?.MyProperty">@MyObject?.MyProperty</span>
```

```
.badge[value="myvalue"]{
    background-color:white;
}
```

The issue with this approch is that

- It require me to re-define custom classes for each value when I already have classes in my css framework i could use
- It can only be applied to a finite list of predefined value
- I can't use a more comple analysis of my value to descide which class to apply (like checking the value with a regex for exemple)

As I'm a bit new to MVVM and data binding, is there a "right" way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like the following, and you can add as many properties as you want, each representing a different CSS class.

```
@page "/"

 <span class="badge badge-primary @myObject?.MyProperty">
                             @myObject?.MyProperty</span>

@code
{
     MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

     public class MyObject
     {
          public string MyProperty { get; set; } = "myvalue";
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps...

Update per suggestion:

```
<span class="badge @statusColor">@myObject?.MyProperty</span> 

@code{

private string color = "red";

public string statusColor
{
    get
    {
        if (myObject?.MyProperty == "something")
            color = "blue";

        return color;
    }
}

MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

public class MyObject
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. My first answer was intended only to demonstrate how you can bind to the span's class attribute, of which you were not aware. As for the rest, you can do whatever you want to achieve your objectives...

Comment: Ho ! I can bid directly into the class, interessting, my only issue is that it doesn't allow me to do some "analysis" on the value (like string operations, regex, etc). Still, thanks for your answer

Comment: So my answer didn't help you ?

Comment: it did a bit, but my main use case is for exemple `if(myObject?.MyProperty.Contain("something") && myObject?.MyOtherProperty == false){//make span badge blue}` which I currently can't do with your or my method

Comment: I found out a way to make it work :  `<span class="badge @statusColor">@myObject?.MyProperty</span>` `public string statusColor { get { if(myObject?.MyProperty == "something") return "blue"; } }` it seem to be refreshed when myObject is updated. If you wish to update your answer to reflect this case, i will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The property approach from the above answer is a bit limited: you must actually have a `statusColor` property for each property you want to colorize. Actually, you can bind a function:

```
<span class="badge badge-primary @(statusColor(myObject?.MyProperty))">@myObject?.MyProperty</span>

@code
{
    private string statusColor(MyClass myProperty) =>
        myProperty switch
        {
           "something" => "blue",
           "somethingelse" => "red",
           _ => "black"
        }
}
```

If your class selection logic is not too complicated, you can even use lambda:

```
<span class="badge badge-primary @(()=> myObject?.MyProperty == "something" ? "blue" : "black")">@myObject?.MyProperty</span>
```